# Calculation of symmetric-decreasing rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, decreasing-rearrangements

I can't image the [symmetric-decreasing rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_decreasing_rearrangement), so , I want to calculate some example, but fail. For example,how to calculate the symmetric-decreasing rearrangement of $f(x)=x$ on $[0,10]$, zero elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) = \chi_{[0,10]}(x) x.$
First step:
$$
\{ x \colon f(x) > t\} 
= \{ x \colon \chi_{[0,10]}(x) x > t\}
= (t \wedge 10, 10]
$$
for $t \ge 0.$
Second step:
$$
|(t \wedge 10, 10]| = 10 - (t \wedge 10) = (10-t)^+.
$$
Third step:
$$
\{x \mid f(x) > t\}^* = \Big\{y \colon |y| < \frac{(10-t)^+}{2}\Big\} 
$$
Final step:
\begin{align*}
f^*(x) &= \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{y \colon f(y) > t\}^*}(x) dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{y \colon |y| < (10-t)^+/2\}}(x) dt\\
&= \int_0^{10} \chi_{\{|x| < (10-t)/2\}} dt\\
&= \int_0^{10} \chi_{\{t < 10 - 2|x|\}} dt\\
&= \int_0^{(10-2|x|)^+}dt\\
&= (10-2|x|)^+\\
&= \chi_{[-5,5]}(x) (10-2|x|).
\end{align*}