# $\frac{1}{|x-y|^\alpha}$ is integrable on the unit ball (center in $~0~$ and radius $~1~$) in $\mathbb R^N~$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I know about the integrability of $~\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}$ in the unit ball (center in $~0~$ and radius $~1~$) when $~\alpha<N~$, but how can I calculate$$\int_C \frac{1}{|x-y|^\alpha}\qquad \text{where $~C~$ is the unit ball and $y$ satisfy $|y|>1$}$$

About $~\alpha~$, I'm thinking in $~\alpha=N+2s~$, where $~N~$ is the space dimension and $~0<s<1~$.

Answer (score 2):

Take hyperspherical coordinates s.t. $\boldsymbol y$ is on the polar axis. Then
$$(\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y) \cdot (\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y) =
r^2 + y^2 - 2 r y \cos \theta.$$
The integral over the remaining $n - 2$ angles will give the surface area of an $(n-2)$-dimensional sphere of radius $1$. Therefore
$$\int_{x < 1} |\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y|^{-\alpha} d\boldsymbol x =
S_{n - 2} \int_0^1 \int_0^\pi
 (r^2 + y^2 - 2 r y \cos \theta)^{-\alpha/2} \hspace {1px}
 r^{n - 1} \sin^{n - 2} \theta \, d\theta dr = \\
\frac {2 \pi^{n/2}} {\Gamma {\left( \frac n 2 \right)}} \int_0^1
 \frac {r^{n - 1}} {(r + y)^\alpha}
 \hspace {1px} {_2 \hspace {-1px} F_1} {\left(
  \frac {n - 1} 2, \frac \alpha 2; n - 1; \frac {4 r y} {(r + y)^2}
 \right)} dr$$
(in one dimension, the integrand is understood as the limit at $n = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question as you, but my $y$ is in the ball, the link is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756719/how-to-prove-int-b-1-frac1x-y-alpha-le-int-b-1-frac1x-alp?noredirect=1&lq=1), r9m kindly told me a new method which is called Rearrangement inequality[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_inequality), you can following the computation in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178548/calculation-of-symmetric-decreasing-rearrangement) to understand how to calculate the rearrangement. I have tried when the $y$ is in the ball, I think for the outside case, it should be the same.

I think this is more intuitive than directly computation.